# Display Youtube channel

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, youtube

I'm looking for the best way to display a list of videos from a specific Youtube channel. Is it correct to parse the html data from the URL, or Apple won't approuve it? I also tried to use a UIWebView, but I can't get only the videos of the channel.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the html files seems like a really complicated and bad idea. Try if you can find something in [YouTube's API](https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/en-GB/).

Comment: It's not that much complicated to parse the HTML file. The problems arrive if Youtube change their files; in that case my code won't work anymore.

I looked in the Youtube API, there is no clear way on how to display a list of videos from a channel. Thank you for trying to help me.